# How to create PictureBoxes with shapes based on a Picture

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, shapes

Problem:
I have pictures of objects on a white background.
I need PictureBoxes that do have the exact shape of these objects, but I do not know how these objects look like a priori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this is a new class:

```
class ShapedPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public ShapedPictureBox()
    {

    }

    public Color transparentColor = Color.White;

    public void updateShape()
    {
    if(this.Image = null) return;
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Image);
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
    for(int x = 0; x < this.Image.Width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < this.Image.Height; y++)
            if(transparentColor != bitmap.GetPixel(x, y))
                graphicsPath.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(1, 1)));
    this.Region = new Region(graphicsPath);
    }
}
```

whenever you invalidate the object the shape will be recreated. I am aware that this solution is not effective at all, but it was the only I found.. I hope it helps someone..

If you have better/more efficient ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Simply use bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

Comment: The very least to improve, is to not trigger the region creation with every Invalidate! Invalidate is not controlled by you; it will happen whenever the system deems it necessary, like after the form is restored from minimize or from having crossed the screen borders.. Instead put it in a function you can call when you change the Image or let LoadCompleted trigger it! - Did you try the solutions in the post I showed you?

Comment: Calling `GetPixel()` for every pixel of an image, every time you invalidate is plain ridiculous to propose as a solution! The `1x1` rectangle makes it even worse.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε well, seeing that in the other case you stated it to be impossible, and seeing that I have not to adapt the shape too often, I think it is a acceptable "solution" though it is extremely inefficient..

Comment: *...you stated it to be impossible* I didn't say that. I said it is very difficult to have a **transparent background picturebox**. You then edited your question and removed the transparency part(white background). Totaly different!

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε ok, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.. I edited the question because of the marking as a duplicate.. I wanted to state clear that just setting the color Transparent won't help..